# Como fazer if em sql - Postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, ireport

Preciso fazer um if no postgres exemplo.

```
SELECT
log."data" AS log_data,
log."tipomovimento" AS log_tipomovimento,
     log."nomefornecedor" AS log_nomefornecedor,
     log."nomeproduto" AS log_nomeproduto
FROM
"public"."log" log
WHERE
     if(log."nomefornecedor" != null) {
 log."data" BETWEEN '2018-01-01' and '2018-06-30'
     and log."tipomovimento" IN ('S') and
    "nomefornecedor" = 'x';
}else{
log."data" BETWEEN '2018-01-01' and '2018-06-30'
     and log."tipomovimento" IN ('S') 
}
```

Se o fornecedor não for nulo ele vai filtrar fornecedor, se for nulo ele não vai filtrar fornecedor no where.
Alguem teria alguma ideia ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do jeito que está na questão, não é preciso usar if nem case. A resposta do @Lisângelo Berti resolve seu problema.

Você não precisa checar se o valor de uma coluna é nula, e então aplicar um filtro. O filtro é para filtrar justamente o valor daquela coluna.

A utilização correta, seria algo assim: O usuário informa o parâmetro para filtrar como nulo. Se ele for nulo, retorna todos os nomes, se não aplica-se o filtro aquela coluna.

Exemplo:

```
WHERE log."data" BETWEEN '2018-01-01' and '2018-06-30' 
and log."tipomovimento" IN ('S')
and 
(case when [parametro] is null then 
    1=1
else
    log."nomefornecedor" = [parametro];
end)
```

Comment: Muito bom, funcionou pra mim, obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Não precisa de IF, utilize OR:

```
where log."data" BETWEEN '2018-01-01' and '2018-06-30'
and log."tipomovimento" IN ('S') 
and (log."nomefornecedor" = null OR "nomefornecedor" = 'x')
```

Comment: Também funcionou, obrigado